# nodejs sequelize - one to one association and mysql workbench

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I want generate a 1:1 relation between two model, to reach my goal I followed the official documentation, apparently I don't have any problem because the models are generated with the relative foreignkey. I recognized a problem when I used the reverse engineering tool of Mysql workbench to check through ER model if the associations where created in a correct way.
How you can see in the model, I declared a one to one relation but in the er diagram Mysql there is a one to many association.

**Crop model:**

```
  Crop.associate = (models) => {
    Crop.hasOne(models.Area, { foreignKey: 'cropId' });
  };
```

**Area model:**

```
  Area.associate = (models) => {
    Area.belongsTo(models.Crop, {foreignKey: 'cropId'});
  };
```

**ER DIAGRAM** (don't care about orchardId foreignkey) 
[image]

Comment: Silly question... but is there a question in here?  Are you asking why is mysql rendering it as a one-to-many while you think you're establishing a one-to-one?

Comment: yes, I would understand why mysql workbench render it as a one to many

Comment: I think that's a one-or-many symbol(?) https://d2slcw3kip6qmk.cloudfront.net/marketing/pages/chart/erd-symbols/ERD-Notation.PNG